# How to fetch date from file name in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have SSIS package with data flow task and execute SQL task components in For each loop container.  Package flow is,  Date flow task(flat file--> Conditional split to insert data into SQL server tables)-->Execute SQL task(perform some SQL operations on inserted data and insert the calculated values in one final analysis table) . File name is like name1_name2_yyyymmdd_1234.txt. I want to fetch the date from file name and insert that date value in table in SQL Server as FileDate. I am trying to do it using derived column but unable to figure our where will I save it so that it will be available in Insert statement in Execute SQL Task which is after Data flow task.

Comment: You save it to a variable. What problem are you having saving it to a variable?

Comment: There are so many examples of how to do this online, here is one from _2011_ https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/ssis-for-each-loop-over-files-with-date-in-name

Answer (score 0):

This should be done outside the dataflow but within the ForEach loop.

Pass in two parameters (package scope) to a script task. One with the `@filename` (read only) from the forloop and to store the @fileDate (read/write).

Split will create a 0-based array in which you only care about the third piece.

```
Dts.Variables["fileDate"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(Dts.Variables["fileName"].Value.Split('_')[2]
                         ,"yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you can use @fileDate anywhere you would like.